# Ajax form not submitted when there are HTML tags in the input field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I've started playing with Ajax and found a (hopefully) little problem I can't seem to find an answer to.

I generate a list of Ajax forms on my page, the code looks like this

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("FixTranslation", new { translationId = errorGroup.Key.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "targetCell_" + errorList.Key.Id }))
{            
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>@errorGroup.SourceText</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="@("targetCell_" + errorGroup.Id)"><input type="text" name="text" id="@("target_" + errorGroup.Id)" value="@(errorGroup.TargetText.Replace(' ', (char)0x00A0))" /><input type="submit" value="Fix" /></td></tr>

                @foreach (var error in errorGroup.Value)
                {            
                    <tr><td>@error.Description</td></tr>
                }                

            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

In the controller I have this action:

```
public ActionResult FixTranslation(string projectId, int translationId, string text)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Content("You entered: " + new HtmlString(text));
    }

    return RedirectToAction("GetProjectOverview", new { projectId = projectId });
}
```

This works fine when there are no angle brackets present in the input field, the form gets sent properly. But when there are some angle brackets (e.g. "This is text with <1>tags") in the input field, my action method does not get called at all.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was not specific to Ajax forms and the cause has been a request validation, which can be turned off in this way for a particular action method:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult FixTranslation(string projectId, int translationId, string text)
{
    ...
}
```